# Do these count as electronics for the purpose of Electro?

Tags: munchkin

I played munchkin marvel for the first time last night and had a problem when we encountered the monster Electro.

The [munchkin marvel](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/) faq (sorry, need to ctrl f to it) did not answer the issue we had.

> Q. Which cards count as "electronic devices" for Electro?
>   A. None. Electro's text means actual electronic devices: smart phones, laptops, etc.

Our issue was centered on what was an electronic device. One of us had a wallet on the table and a player with an engineering physics degree argued that all of the cards with tap and pay type technology counted, but that chip cards and swipe cards were not. There was also a phone which had some high tech stylus which had a button and was argued that it was part of the phone as well as being its own electronic device. Are these valid examples of electronics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most basic definition of electronic device is probably anything which has one or more transistors (or possibly diodes), and which is thus leveraging the tunneling of electrons across a heterogeneous semi-conductor boundary.

> **Electronic devices** are components for controlling the flow of electrical currents for the purpose of information processing and system control. Prominent examples include transistors and diodes.

I would agree with your Eng. Phys. friend on everything except for chip devices. [The chip on a chip card is actually a small CPU](http://money.howstuffworks.com/personal-finance/debt-management/chip-and-pin-credit-cards1.htm) which receives power once inserted into the reader, thus clearly passing the possessing transistors test:

> The computer chip inside a chip and PIN card functions like a small computer. Not only can the chip store data, but it's also a data processor. One of the reasons why chip and PIN cards are so secure is that the chip uses cryptography to protect secure data when communicating with a card reader. The chip itself has no power source, but it leaps into action when it comes in contact with a checkout terminal.

However, as with all ***Munchkin*** games, the [final rule arbiter](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf) is always the owner of the primary game set being played.

> Any other dispute should be settled by loud argument, with the owner of the game having the last word.

Comment: Everything other than the last quote is irrelevant, really. When I first started reading your answer I thought I was going to downvote it, but you saved it right at the end.

Comment: @AndyT: Interesting! My thinking is: What good is a loud argument without numerous and sound talking points.

Comment: Yep, fair enough. The first part of your answer is good and should help the OP, but is more suited to Electronics.SE. I was just worried (at first) that you weren't going to quote the "settled by loud argument" rule, which is the boardgames.SE answer.